# Preventing Crystal report's Excel export from Wraping Text

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm exporting my crystal report's output into Excel file but the text is (by default) wrapped. 
 Is there any way I can prevent the text from wrapping in Excel?
 Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You export report output into **Excel (Data Only)**. This solution will not wrapped the text but might remove the header and footer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get around to it using the "Maintain relative object positioing" option inside "Export report option".

Comment: Not a plausible answer. The fact that you are changing the output makes other formatting options disabled.